# How to get the color of pixel openlayes 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I'm trying to get the color of the pixel from the map in Openlayers 2. 
Or is there is a function to get xyz values from rgb?

Comment: What do you mean by "function to get xyz values from rgb"? Did you actually mean "function to get rgb values from xyz "?

Comment: yes exactly with openlayers 2

Comment: Have a look at example http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/canvas-inspector.html. It looks complicated but is seems to work.

Comment: yeah , but the thing is i am not using canvas